# I can't get pagination to work in WP query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is what my current wordpress post query looks like:

```
<?php
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 5 
    ) );
?>
```

I want to add the following pagination to it:

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Prev'),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next'),
) ); ?>
```

I googled for various solutions. Everywhere it said to add "paged" to the array, like so:

```
<?php
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;**
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'paged' => $paged,**
    'posts_per_page' => 5 // put number of posts that you'd like to display
    ) );
?>
```

**However, this does not work. How can I get the pagination to work in a custom wordpress post query?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the argument: `'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) )`

After you run your loop, you can add this function in your theme(functions.php or elsewhere):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_pagination' ) ) {

    function custom_pagination( $args = array(), $class = 'pagination' ) {

        if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1 ) {
            return;
        }

        $args = wp_parse_args(
            $args,
            array(
                'mid_size'           => 3,
                'prev_next'          => true,
                'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous', 'theme' ),
                'next_text'          => __( 'Next', 'theme' ),
                'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation', 'theme' ),
                'type'               => 'array',
                'current'            => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                //'total'           => $the_query->max_num_pages,
            )
        );

        $links = paginate_links( $args );

        ?>

        <nav aria-label="<?php echo $args['screen_reader_text']; ?>">

            <ul class="pagination">

                <?php
                foreach ( $links as $key => $link ) {
                    ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?php echo strpos( $link, 'current' ) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                        <?php echo str_replace( 'page-numbers', 'page-link', $link ); ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>

            </ul>

        </nav>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Then finally call it in whatever template you need to:

```
custom_pagination();
```